# How to send a message to paired device by bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, message

Hi I would like to send a simple message to another device by bluetooth. Simple 'a' which will appear in textView in another device.

I've managed to pair devices, but now I've got only one problem, how to send a message, or even variable to another device, by clicking on the button.

This is my class which is responsible for connection

```
public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {


    private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
            UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");
  //  private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private int mState;

    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

    public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";
   // private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device
    private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 2;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;
    ListView listViewPaired;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListpaired;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter,detectedAdapter;
    BluetoothDevice bdDevice;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListBluetoothDevices = null;
    ListItemClicked listItemClicked;
    ListView newDevicesListView;


    private static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";
    //making btAdapter and ArrayAdapter
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;
    public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);

        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // onclicklistener for discovering devices
        Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doDiscovery();
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        // FOR DISCOVERY

        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        // Find and set up the ListView for newly discovered devices
        newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
        newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
        /////////////////newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        DeviceListActivity.this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        DeviceListActivity.this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // FOR PAIRED
        ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        pairedListView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
        ////////////////////////pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                pairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
           }
        } else {
            String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
           pairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
        }





        arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        arrayListpaired = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayListBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(DeviceListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListpaired);
        listItemClicked = new ListItemClicked();


}

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }


    private void doDiscovery() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doDiscovery()");

        // Indicate scanning in the title
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        setTitle(R.string.scanning);

        // Turn on sub-title for new devices
        findViewById(R.id.title_new_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
        mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                if(arrayListBluetoothDevices.size()<1) // this checks if the size of bluetooth device is 0,then add the
                {                                           // device to the arraylist.
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
            }



            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                setTitle(R.string.select_device);
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                }
            }
        }
    };

class ListItemClicked implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bdDevice = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
        //bdClass = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
        Log.i("Log", "The dvice : "+bdDevice.toString());
            /*
             * here below we can do pairing without calling the callthread(), we can directly call the
             * connect(). but for the safer side we must usethe threading object.
             */
        //callThread();
        //connect(bdDevice);
        Boolean isBonded = false;
        try {
            isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
            if(isBonded)
            {
                //arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                getPairedDevices();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//connect(bdDevice);
        Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded);
    }
}


    public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)
            throws Exception
    {
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);
        return returnValue.booleanValue();
    }


    private void getPairedDevices() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(pairedDevice.size()>0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice)
            {
                arrayListpaired.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.add(device);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        getPairedDevices();
        newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClicked);
    }

}
```

This is my XML File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="69dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_send"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You have asked this same question multiple times. Please don't repost.

Answer (score 3):

But if you want to build a bluetooth application, you should understand basic concepts. Did you read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) theory about Bluetooth API?

Then look at [this](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothChat/project.html) android sample project. Analyse the code in `BluetoothChatService.java` class.

At the end of the `BluetoothChatService.java` class you should notice 3 Thread's classes. When the application starts, both android devices act as servers so they are waiting for incoming connection (`Socket`). On both devices `AcceptThread` thread is running and it's waiting for connection. Then one of them decides to connect to another so it starts `ConnectThread` thread. There you are sending your `Socket` to the server. So on one device server catches this `Socket` in `AcceptThread` and on another device you get this `Socket` connected in `ConnectThread`. Now you are starting `ConnectedThread` on both devices with connected `Socket`. There you simply get `InputStream` and `OutputStream` to get bytes respectivelly send bytes. Then in endless `while` loop you waiting for incoming bytes and send bytes using `public void write(byte[] buffer)` method of your `BluetoothChatService` object.

Comment: I was trying to use this example in my program, but it is too complicated. I do not know which methods i should use to manage this issue.

Comment: But if you want to build a bluetooth application, you should understand basic concepts. Did you read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) theory about Bluetooth API?

Comment: Yes, several times. I've already paired devices, the thing is, i would like to send some string variable by pushing on the button. This variable should appear in TextView on another device. I'm new in android, I used those ConnectThread and ConnectedThreads, but it did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Ok I worked something out. My chat is working on both devices, but nothing show up on the second device after clicking SEND button. Thanks for describing :)

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private InputStream mmInStream;
    private OutputStream mmOutStream;
    //private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private EditText mOutEditText;
    private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Button mSendButton;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
    String tag = "debugging";
    private ListView mConversationView;
    protected static final int SUCCESS_CONNECT = 0;
    protected static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
            UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;
    private static final String NAME_SECURE = "BluetoothChatSecure";
    private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BluetoothChatInsecure";

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // variables
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.content_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.discoverable:
                ensureDiscoverable();
                return true;
            case R.id.secure_connect_scan:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.disconnect:
                mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

    private void ensureDiscoverable() {
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            startActivity(discoverableIntent);

    }





    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }


    Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(tag, "in handler");
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch(msg.what){
                case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                    // DO something
                    ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CONNECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String s = "successfully connected";
                    connectedThread.write(s.getBytes());
                    Log.i(tag, "connected");
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
                    String string = new String(readBuf);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };


    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything

        // Check that there's actually something to send
        if (message.length() > 0) {
            // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
            //  byte[] send = message.getBytes();
            //   mChatService.write(send);

            String messagess="blabla";
            byte[] send = messagess.getBytes();
            write(send);

            // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
            mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
            mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
        }
    }


    private void setupChat() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

        // Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread
        mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.content_main);

        mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);

        // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
     //   mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);

        // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Send a message using content of the edit text widget


                    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
                    String message = textView.getText().toString();
                    sendMessage(message);

            }
        });


        // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
        mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
    }


/*    private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener
            = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                String message = view.getText().toString();
                sendMessage(message);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };*/


    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
        private String mSocketType;

        public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                            MY_UUID_SECURE);
                } else {
                    tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                            NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                    "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                            case STATE_LISTEN:
                            case STATE_CONNECTING:
                                // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                               // connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                //        mSocketType);
                                break;
                            case STATE_NONE:
                            case STATE_CONNECTED:
                                // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                                try {
                                    socket.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

        }

        public void cancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "cancel " + this);
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
       /* if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            // Otherwise, setup the chat session
        }*/
            setupChat();

    }







}
```

Comment: And where are you connecting to the device? You implemented server side, but not host, when you are connecting, so you are waiting for connection but not create any... Look at `ConnectThread` class in `BluetoothChatService`

Answer (score 0):

But those devices are already paired, or am I getting it wrong.

Here is a class which is responsible for connecting and then for pairing devices.

```
public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListpaired;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter,detectedAdapter;
    BluetoothDevice bdDevice;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListBluetoothDevices = null;
    ListItemClicked listItemClicked;
    ListView newDevicesListView;


    private static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";
    //making btAdapter and ArrayAdapter
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);

        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // onclicklistener for discovering devices
        Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doDiscovery();
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        // FOR DISCOVERY

        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        // Find and set up the ListView for newly discovered devices
        newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
        newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
        /////////////////newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        DeviceListActivity.this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        DeviceListActivity.this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // FOR PAIRED
        ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        pairedListView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
        ////////////////////////pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                pairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        } else {
            String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
            pairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
        }





        arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        arrayListpaired = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayListBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(DeviceListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListpaired);
        listItemClicked = new ListItemClicked();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }


    private void doDiscovery() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doDiscovery()");

        // Indicate scanning in the title
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        setTitle(R.string.scanning);

        // Turn on sub-title for new devices
        findViewById(R.id.title_new_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
        mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                if(arrayListBluetoothDevices.size()<1) // this checks if the size of bluetooth device is 0,then add the
                {                                           // device to the arraylist.
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
            }



            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                setTitle(R.string.select_device);
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    class ListItemClicked implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bdDevice = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            //bdClass = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            Log.i("Log", "The dvice : "+bdDevice.toString());
            /*
             * here below we can do pairing without calling the callthread(), we can directly call the
             * connect(). but for the safer side we must usethe threading object.
             */
            //callThread();
            //connect(bdDevice);
            Boolean isBonded = false;
            try {
                isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
                if(isBonded)
                {
                    //arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    getPairedDevices();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }//connect(bdDevice);
            Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded);
        }
    }


    public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)
            throws Exception
    {
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);
        return returnValue.booleanValue();
    }


    private void getPairedDevices() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(pairedDevice.size()>0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice)
            {
                arrayListpaired.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.add(device);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        getPairedDevices();
        newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClicked);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth communication includes the following steps:

1. bluetoothadapter.startDiscovery(); (You are done)
2. createBond(BluetoothDevice device);

```
 private boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice device) {
        return device.createBond();
    }
```

3. connect(BluetoothDevice device); (You need to call it in a child thread)

```
    private void connect(BluetoothDevice device){
        try {
            BluetoothSocket mBluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BltContant.SPP_UUID);
            if (mBluetoothSocket != null) {
                if (bluetoothadapter.isDiscovering()) {
                    bluetoothadapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
                if (!mBluetoothSocket.isConnected()) {

                    mBluetoothSocket.connect();
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                mBluetoothSocket.close();

            }catch (Exception e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

4. sendMessage(String message); (You can use `SendSocketService.sendMessage("mesage");` to send your info)

```
/**
 * send message
 */
public class SendSocketService {

    /**
     * send txt message
     *
     * @param message
     */
    public static void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (APP.bluetoothSocket == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) return;
        try {
            message += "\n";
            OutputStream outputStream = APP.bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(message.getBytes("utf-8"));
            outputStream.flush();
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageBean(BltContant.SEND_TEXT_SUCCESS));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * send file
     */
    public static void sendMessageByFile(String filePath) {
        if (APP.bluetoothSocket == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath)) return;
        try {
            OutputStream outputStream = APP.bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            //file path
            File file = new File(filePath);
            //file is not exist
            if (!file.exists()){
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageBean(BltContant.SEND_FILE_NOTEXIT));
                return;
            }


            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageBean(BltContant.SEND_FILE_IS_FOLDER));
                return;
            }


            outputStream.write("file".getBytes("utf-8"));

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            int fileSize = 0; 
            while ((length = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
                fileSize += length;
                Log.i("socketChat", "file upload：" + (fileSize / file.length() * 100) + "%");

                outputStream.write(b, 0, length);
            }

            fis.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageBean(BltContant.SEND_FILE_SUCCESS));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```